Binomial distribution as sum of Bernoulis - Independent?
Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be bernouly with the same probability $p\in [0,1]$. Consider their sum $X=X_1+...+X_n$. It is common knowledge that if they are independent, then $X$ is binomially distributed. However, the emphasis of my question, is: what sort of independence is required, and why?
If $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are mutually independent, then $X$ is binomially distributed. But what if $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is only pairwise independent. Would that suffice for $X$ to be binomially distirbuted? And if not, which counterexample will disprove it?

Try yourself to construct any example where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are pairwise independent but not mutually independent. (It is not too hard.) Then see if that example gives you a binomial distribution for $X_1+X_2+X_3$. (I doubt it will.)

bernouly $\leftrightarrow$ Bernoulli.

If you can't construct the example suggested by Henry, see here for the classical example.

Pairwise independence is not sufficient to conclude a sum of Bernoulli random variables is binomially distributed.
Here is an example with $21$ random variables, each with probability $1/6$. You have seven dice, each with a different color, and roll all the dice simultaneously. There are $\binom 72=21$ pairs of dice. For each pair of dice, there is a Bernoulli random variable, which is equal to $1$ if those two dice show the same number, and zero otherwise.
These $21$ indicator variables are pairwise independent. This is obvious when the pairs involve four distinct dice; the event of the red die equalling the orange die is independent of the green die equalling the blue die. Less obviously, the event of red equalling orange is also independent of orange equalling yellow.
The sum of these variables is not binomial. In particular, there will always be at least one pair of equal dice, as there are seven dice but only six faces. However, for a nontrivial binomial random variable, there is always a nonzero chance of that variable being zero.
